# Можно не использовать django framewrok в некоторых местах?

Tags: фреймворк

Доброго времени суток дорогие друзья!
Я вот хотел спросить про Джанго и Пайтон.
С помощью чистого Пайтона ( без Джанго ) можно создать веб приложение и не париться?
И я слышал что Джанго не легкий, люди говорили мне например:
Чтобы создать Лэндинг не нужно использовать Джанго, ибо там будет форма и все.
Вот эти слова насколько правда?